# In Rails, is there an update_all that only overwrites null entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails, is there an update_all that only overwrites null entries? I want to record the first time something happened, but not overwrite it if it was already set.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the update_all method after finding the records you need. It bypasses callbacks and validations however is blazing fast and useful on large datasets. Something like:

```
 #Change out :some_field  with whatever field you want to check
YourModel.where(some_field: nil).update_all(some_field: Time.now)
```